# simpledateformat to currenttimemillis-like format

Tags: simpledateformat

Is there a way to bring back a date formatted with **SimpleDateFormat** to its long equivalent (like **System.currentTimeMillis()**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = format.parse(VALUE).getTime();
```

Simplest way I can think of.

Comment: I did it successfully..But, i just notice that when i create a new simpleDateFormat object, its translation(.parse()) is not the date I formatted before...Any explanation about this?

Comment: My explanation is maybe you have the month and day mixed up? Otherwise I am a littler perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) to get a `Date` object, and then call [`getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) on that `Date` object.

That'll give you the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (same as [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)).

Comment: I did it successfully..But, i just notice that when i create a new simpleDateFormat object, its translation(.parse()) is not the date I formatted before...Any explanation about this?